# Different sizeof() of struct and class with the same field types in each other

Tags: c++

I already know, that in structure there are paddings between fields, and size of whole structure depends on their order or something like that.
But does it work the same way for classes?

I have some struct like:

```
typedef struct {
    char *b;
    int s;
} class_t;
```

And I also have a class with the same fields:

```
class Class{
private:
    char *m_buf;
    int m_size;
};
```

The question is: why sizeof(class_t) gives 16 bytes, and sizeof(Class) gives 12 bytes?

Comment: I am not seeing any difference in my testing using g++ 5.4.0. You may want to add your platform details.

Comment: There should be no difference. Which compiler are you using? I know MSVC treats `struct` and `class` slightly differently at some level.

Comment: I can get the same 16/12 numbers by tagging the class with `__attribute__((packed))` on gcc. Many codebases hide these attributes in macros for portability. Perhaps you are running into something like this? (https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/XEkH7f)

Comment: Can you disclose the optimization level of the compilation, too?

Comment: I am using
g++ (Ubuntu 7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04) 7.3.0

Comment: @Frank was right
I was dealing with someone else's code, and it had #pragma pack(push, 1), that caused the difference in sizeof()

Comment: So, how can I mark @Frank 's comment as an answer?

Comment: @XoMute: I made my comment into an answer now that it's been confirmed, and not just a hunch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 12 number is suspicious. It's a bit of a weird size, and tells me the compiler is doing something funky with the layout.

Since you mentionned GCC, I would imagine that struct packing has been enabled on that class, either through `__attribute__((packed))` (most likely in a macro), or via the `pack()` pragma somehow.

You can see this behavior in action here: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/XEkH7f

Comment: Well, an 8-byte pointer plus a 4-byte integer resulting in a packed 12-byte class isn't that "weird"...

Comment: @Bob__ it's weird because `alignof(char*)` is typically 8, so structs that start with a pointer will typically have their size padded to the nearest 8 so that arrays of the struct maintain correct alignment.(This is not 100% correct, but the gist of the principle remains) I know that's the case in OP's situation since the struct gets padded this way.

Answer (score 2):

Except for the fact that a  `struct` and a `class` have different default access specifications and different default inheritance (`public` vs `private`), a `class` and a struct are *exactly* the same.